# Email reminders for a case

Tags: civicase, civirules, scheduled-reminders

I’m using Civi 5.68.1 on WP. I want to create auto reminders for the case ahead of a deadline, which is stored as a custom field on the case. I assume Scheduled Reminders would have been the obvious option, as this is what it is for, but those are not set to work with cases. One option I thought about is to create an activity for it and have it included in the case. Scheduled Reminders can work with Activities. However, as far as I can see, it must built around the Activity date. So, I tried to create a rule to copy the case custom date field to the Activity date. The challenge here is as describes here [CiviRules "Update Date Value" - I cannot select any source or target field](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45123/civirules-update-date-value-i-cannot-select-any-source-or-target-field) (and it is the same for the Rule Action Advanced Update Date Value). Second option I thought is to create a Rule Action which will create a case activity of type Email. The plus for this option is a very easy way to time the email, even based on my case custom date field. The downside is the lack of flexibility for selecting recipients. The only option is to select a specific contact, rather than based on case roles or other relative selection rules. What other options I have?